# Easiest way to do SSO between a Spring MVC/Boot Application and Alfresco Community Edition

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, single-sign-on, alfresco, alfresco-share

I have a Spring MVC/Boot Application which I am trying to integrate with Alfresco CE 5.2.e or later. The Spring MVC app contains links to some Alfresco CE documents. I have the same usernames and passwords in both. When I should log in my own application, clicking an Alfresco CE document link should redirect me to the document page without going through the Share Login page.
1) What's the easiest way to configure Alfresco CE so that I can bypass the Share login page? 
2) Is there a way to automatically log me in Alfresco CE behind the scenes when I log in my appplication?
Is there an easier way than customizing SSOAuthenticationFilter.java or a good example for the same?

*Note: I do not want to set up complex SSO mechanisms or CAS, OAuth, LDAP etc. alf_ticket only gives you access but does not let you bypass share login page.

Answer (score 0):

You could either setup SSO, or use "alf_ticket" for each of your requests towards Alfresco.

https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/#!/authentication/validateTicket

Comment: Hi Lista. I am looking for a solution not involving configuration of complex SSO(ntlm, ldap, cas etc). Also the alf_ticket only gives you access to Share repository but does not let you bypass the login page.

Comment: Why would you build a URL that targets Share when all you want to do is download a document? This is done easily by hitting the /alfresco context directly, and, as Lista pointed out, the alf_ticket can be used as the credential.

Comment: Hi Jeff. I am not looking for downloading a document, rather opening the document's detailed page.